# MySQL Left Join Right Join union returns incorrect data

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, union, right-join

My classmates and I have been run rampant trying to get this query to work correctly.

**Goal:** Return a single table that consists of two tables fully joined by means of a left join and then a right join. There will be null values. The purpose of this table is to graph both speed and weight with speed on the left Y-axis and weight on the right Y-axis in order to track how weight coincides with speed. Some values will have shared dates.

**The Assumptions:**

- A player cannot record their weight multiple times in a day.
- A player cannot have multiple sprint speed entries in a single day.
- No date can exist independent of AT LEAST a sprint value OR a weight. They must have AT LEAST one of the values associated with it.

**The Issue:** Several rows are returning values when they should be NULL instead, and we have no clue where this data is coming from.

**Current Incorrect Query:**

```
SELECT weight.username, weight.weight, metric.speedOrDistance, weighInDate  
FROM playerweight as weight LEFT JOIN sprint AS metric ON
weight.weighInDate = metric.workoutDate 
WHERE weight.username = 'testuser' 
UNION  
SELECT metric.username, weight.weight,
metric.speedOrDistance, workoutDate 
FROM playerweight as weight RIGHT
JOIN sprint AS metric ON weight.weighInDate = metric.workoutDate 
WHERE metric.username = 'testuser' 
ORDER BY weighInDate;
```

**Example Data:**

sprint Table

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| username | workoutDate | speedOrDistance |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| jdoe     | 2016-10-10  |            2.00 |
| jdoe     | 2016-10-17  |            3.50 |
| jdoe     | 2016-10-24  |            3.00 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-01  |            5.00 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-10  |            4.00 |
| foo      | 2016-11-03  |            2.50 |
| foo      | 2016-11-14  |            5.00 |
| foo      | 2016-11-16  |            4.00 |
| foo      | 2016-11-18  |            3.00 |
| testuser | 2016-10-11  |            3.40 |
| testuser | 2016-10-17  |            3.40 |
| testuser | 2016-11-13  |            1.50 |
| testuser | 2016-11-15  |            2.00 |
| testuser | 2016-11-17  |            4.00 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

playerWeight

```
+----------+-------------+--------+
| username | weighInDate | weight |
+----------+-------------+--------+
| jdoe     | 2016-10-10  |    160 |
| jdoe     | 2016-10-17  |    160 |
| jdoe     | 2016-10-24  |    170 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-01  |    180 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-08  |    180 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-09  |    200 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-11  |    178 |
| jdoe     | 2016-11-22  |    195 |
| foo      | 2016-11-01  |    190 |
| foo      | 2016-11-10  |    185 |
| foo      | 2016-11-14  |    175 |
| foo      | 2016-11-18  |    180 |
| bar      | 2011-01-16  |    170 |
| bar      | 2011-07-16  |    177 |
| bar      | 2011-09-16  |    169 |
| testuser | 2016-11-04  |    150 |
| testuser | 2016-11-08  |    200 |
| testuser | 2016-11-11  |    195 |
| testuser | 2016-11-14  |    175 |
| testuser | 2016-11-17  |    180 |
+----------+-------------+--------+
```

**Incorrect Result Table**

```
+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| username | weight | speedOrDistance | weighInDate |
+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| testuser | NULL   | 3.4             | 2016-10-11  |
| testuser | 160    | 3.4             | 2016-10-17  | -- ERROR ROW, weight should not have a value
| testuser | 150    | NULL            | 2016-11-04  |
| testuser | 200    | NULL            | 2016-11-08  |
| testuser | 195    | NULL            | 2016-11-11  |
| testuser | NULL   | 1.5             | 2016-11-13  |
| testuser | 175    | 5               | 2016-11-14  | -- ERROR ROW, speedOrDistance should not have a value
| testuser | NULL   | 2               | 2016-11-15  |
| testuser | 180    | 4               | 2016-11-17  |
+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

**Ideal Result Table**

```
+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| username | weight | speedOrDistance | weighInDate |
+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
| testuser | NULL   | 3.4             | 2016-10-11  |
| testuser | NULL   | 3.4             | 2016-10-17  |
| testuser | 150    | NULL            | 2016-11-04  |
| testuser | 200    | NULL            | 2016-11-08  |
| testuser | 195    | NULL            | 2016-11-11  |
| testuser | NULL   | 1.5             | 2016-11-13  |
| testuser | 175    | NULL            | 2016-11-14  |
| testuser | NULL   | 2               | 2016-11-15  |
| testuser | 180    | 4               | 2016-11-17  |
+----------+--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Any help that you guys could offer would be greatly appreciated. We have no idea why this isn't working.

**Thank You!!!**

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off using a `FULL JOIN` rather than a `UNION`, `LEFT JOIN`, and a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Mysql doesn't support full joins.

Comment: I just tested this and cannot confirm these wrong rows. I guess, in your test environment you have different example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do the joins on `workoutDate = weighInDate`. This gives you combinations of unrelated rows, which remain in the result set, even with unrelated user names.

To fix this, you must join on both dates and usernames, e.g.

```
LEFT JOIN sprint AS metric ON weight.weighInDate = metric.workoutDate
                              and weight.username = metric.username
```

similarly on right join, of course.

---

Added to the answer because it helps illustrate the cause of the problem. The @OlafDietsche has the correct solution. I just wanted you to see where the actual wrong data came from.

To show you the problem with your join this record:

```
| testuser | 2016-10-17  |            3.40
```

is joining to this record

```
| jdoe     | 2016-10-17  |    160 |
```

because you only joined on date.